# Cordova/PhoneGap: Trouble hiding ActivityIndicator on iOS

Tags: cordova

I'm using Cordova/PhoneGap and the ActivityIndicator Plugin on iOS. For some reason the spinner doesn't hide when I call 'ActivityIndicator.hide()' from the callback function.

Any ideas appreciated.

Thanks!

```
            ActivityIndicator.show();

            // Get the search term
            var searchStr = $("#input-field").val().trim();

            // Test Get Request
            m.dataFetcher.getItemsByName(searchStr, function(res, data) {
                if (res) {
                    // Load List View
                    that.loadListView(data);
                }
                // this call doesn't work: 
                ActivityIndicator.hide();
            });
```

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

the Activity Indicator started to appear for me when I switched from Ajax REST calls to using Corvoda Wymsee plugin with a native HTTP client implementation. I'm not sure if this is the right answer but it worked for me.